# Uploading a large AVCHD video file to facebook

Tags: facebook, video, upload

What is the best way to upload a ~700MB of AVCHD (1080p, 50fps) video file to facebook to get the best performance?

Uploading it the regular way gets video and audio out of sync, and the video appears "stuttering"...

Maybe convert it to so some sort of format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user handbrake (http://handbrake.fr) to convert it into mp4 format (the normal preset).

Comment: Can I use other video converter as well, like wondershare? Should I convert it to 1920*1080 or 1280*720?